# How right start delayed Route and get STATUS ?(Camel v3 !!!)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

```
builder.from(fileOptions.toString())
                .id("rabbitMQ")
                .noAutoStartup()
```

Маке start route:

```
        Route route = camelContext.getRoute("rabbitMQ");
        route.warmUp();
        ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
```

Route is started but status is 0 (ServiceStatus.Stopped)

```
   if (route instanceof EventDrivenConsumerRoute)
            info.setStatus(((EventDrivenConsumerRoute) route).getStatus());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RouteController` API from `CamelContext` to control and start routes.

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-controller.html

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you accept [Claus Ibsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348767/7193761)'s  answer?
Here ist more code to implement waht he said:

```
CamelContext ctx = route.getCamelContext();
// To list all routes in the context with their status
ctx.getRoutes().forEach(r->log.info("Route[RouteId: '{}', status: '{}']", r.getRouteId(), ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(r.getRouteId())));

if (ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(route.getRouteId())!= ServiceStatus.Started) {
    try{
        log.info(String.format("Starting Route[routeId:'%s', status:'%s'] ..",
                        route.getRouteId(), ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(route.getRouteId())));

        ctx.getRouteController().startRoute(route.getRouteId());            
        while(ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(route.getRouteId())!= ServiceStatus.Started) {}
        log.info("Route '{}' is now {}.", route.getRouteId(), ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(route.getRouteId()));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Starting Route Failed", ex);
    }   
} else {
   log.info(String.format("Route[routeId:'%s' already '%s'] ..", route.getRouteId(),ctx.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(route.getRouteId())));
}
```